# pytorch linear regression given wrong results

Tags: linear-regression, pytorch

I implemented a simple linear regression and I’m getting some poor results. Just wondering if these results are normal or I’m making some mistake.

I tried different optimizers and learning rates, I always get bad/poor results

Here is my code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torch.autograd import Variable 

class LinearRegressionPytorch(nn.Module):

   def __init__(self, input_dim=1, output_dim=1):

       super(LinearRegressionPytorch, self).__init__()
       self.linear = nn.Linear(input_dim, output_dim)

   def forward(self,x):
       x = x.view(x.size(0),-1)
       y = self.linear(x)
       return y

input_dim=1 
output_dim = 1
if torch.cuda.is_available():
   model = LinearRegressionPytorch(input_dim, output_dim).cuda()
else:
   model = LinearRegressionPytorch(input_dim, output_dim) 

criterium = nn.MSELoss()
l_rate =0.00001
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=l_rate)
#optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=l_rate)
epochs = 100

#create data
x = np.random.uniform(0,10,size = 100) #np.linspace(0,10,100); 
y = 6*x+5
mu = 0
sigma = 5
noise =  np.random.normal(mu, sigma, len(y))
y_noise = y+noise

#pass it to pytorch
x_data = torch.from_numpy(x).float()
y_data = torch.from_numpy(y_noise).float()
if torch.cuda.is_available():
   inputs = Variable(x_data).cuda()
   target = Variable(y_data).cuda()
else:
   inputs = Variable(x_data)
   target = Variable(y_data)

for epoch in range(epochs):

   #predict data
   pred_y= model(inputs)

   #compute loss
   loss = criterium(pred_y, target)

   #zero grad and optimization
   optimizer.zero_grad()
   loss.backward()
   optimizer.step()

   #if epoch % 50 == 0:
   #   print(f'epoch = {epoch}, loss =  {loss.item()}')


#print params
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
   if param.requires_grad:
       print(name, param.data)
```

There are the poor results :

```py
linear.weight tensor([[1.7374]], device='cuda:0')
linear.bias tensor([0.1815], device='cuda:0')
```

The results should be weight = 6 , bias = 5

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please edit your question posting only [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Error is not with your plotting, why is it in the code? It's just making noise and making it harder for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem Solution

Actually your `batch_size` is problematic. If you have it set as one, your `target`needs the same shape as outputs (which you are, correctly, reshaping with `view(-1, 1)`).

Your loss should be defined like this:

```
loss = criterium(pred_y, target.view(-1, 1))
```

This network is correct

## Results

Your results **will not be** `bias=5` (yes, `weight` will go towards `6` indeed) as you are adding random noise to `target` (and as it's a single value for all your data points, only `bias` will be affected).

If you want `bias` equal to `5` remove addition of noise.

**You should increase number of your epochs as well, as your data is quite small and network (linear regression in fact) is not really powerful.** `10000` say should be fine and your loss should oscillate around `0` (if you change your noise to something sensible).

### Noise

You are creating multiple gaussian distributions with different variations, hence your loss would be higher. Linear regression is unable to fit your data and find sensible bias (as the optimal slope is still approximately `6` for your noise, you may try to increase multiplication of `5` to `1000` and see what `weight` and `bias` will be learned).

## Style (a little offtopic)

Please read documentation about PyTorch and keep your code up to date (e.g. `Variable` is deprecated in favor of `Tensor` and rightfully so).

This part of code:

```
x_data = torch.from_numpy(x).float()
y_data = torch.from_numpy(y_noise).float()
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    inputs = Tensor(x_data).cuda()
    target = Tensor(y_data).cuda()
else:
    inputs = Tensor(x_data)
    target = Tensor(y_data)
```

Could be written succinctly like this (without much thought):

```
inputs = torch.from_numpy(x).float()
target = torch.from_numpy(y_noise).float()
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    inputs = inputs.cuda()
    target = target.cuda()
```

I know deep learning has it's reputation for bad code and fatal practice, but **please** do not help spreading this approach.